# “Is there a way you could/would accept?”

Tags: letter-writing

Is it correct to write this in a formal letter:

> My certificate is not valid anymore. Is there a way you could accept my expired certificate?"

Or should I use *would* instead of *could*? And what is the difference between those two?

Comment: Looks OK. You may want to tell them how long ago your certificate expires, as that may affect whether they will accept it.

Comment: Thank you TrevorD. Why didn't you post it as an answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *Is there a way you could?* is asking a factual question; do the regulations allow for expired certificates in any circumstances, and if so when?  This unfortunately invites the response 'Sorry, rule 7 requires a valid certificate'.

If you already know that, but you are pleading for a minor indulgence, what's wrong with *please accept my expired certificate in the circumstances*, which allows you to bring in all the reasons why they should be sympathetic?

Comment: +1 *Could* deals with possibilities (usually physical or legal), *would* deals with choices. "If he *could* fly *would* he choose to do so?"

Answer (score 3):

I think it is fine.

I would write "would".  To steal and potentially misapply from GrammerCop [*sic*]:

*Would* is definite, but conditional--it will happen if certain conditions are met. *Could* is a possibility--it may or may not come to be.